# Realtime GetPixel

Tags: java, android

> I wanted to get pixel value in realtime without clicking the screen.

`

```
sl.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
sl.buildDrawingCache(true);

bitmap = sl.getDrawingCache();
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int) 39, (int) 31);

int r = Color.red(pixel);
int g = Color.red(pixel);
int b = Color.red(pixel);

cl.setText("R("+r+")\n"+"G("+g+")\n"+"B("+b+")");
Log.d("Color Detection: ","R("+r+") "+"G("+g+") "+"B("+b+")"+Tracker.labelString.length());
```

`

I wanted to getpixel value in realtime infront of the camera.
[image: example]

Comment: If by "infront of the camera", you mean from a camera preview, you cannot get that from a drawing cache. However, you can get access to preview frames, such as [via CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Not sure what you mean by 'pixel infront of the camera'. I'm going to assume you want to do analysis of a live camera preview. In which case have you read: https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze (and done the codelab?)

Comment: Thanks i find little info about this, that's why i attempting to know how does it work .

Comment: @MorrisonChang Can you give me an example how does it work?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. The codelab provides a sample implementation, searching on "github android camerax samples" leads to: https://github.com/android/camera-samples Image processing in general is a broad subject. Android is doing a lot of stuff between the camera sensor and giving you a bitmap.